# how to remove empty div

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
$('.custompsps').each(function(i, obj)  {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $items = $this.find(".custom_blank_wrapper")
      $.each($items, function(n, e)
      {
         ($items).(".custom_blank"): is blank or not 
      });
 });
```

I want to remove empty div of custompsps div which has all div empty how can i remove it
custompsps which has empty tag and filled tag should not be affected i think i need to run two loops for it but i have do idea how to achieve it  i know is is simple I am stuck her so can someone help me with this issue

```html
<div class="custompsps">
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
            <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
            <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
                <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
                <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="custompsps">
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
            <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            <div class="custom_blank"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any span tag in your code

Comment: my mistake its div

Answer (score 1):

Use this following code which will remove all 'custom_blank_wrapper' div, if it's all child 'custom_blank' div is empty.

```
$('.custompsps .custom_blank_wrapper').each(function(i, obj)  {
    var customBlankWrapperChild = $(this).children();
    var customBlankWrapperChildCount=customBlankWrapperChild.length;
    var emptyBlankWrapperChildCount=0;
    for(i=0; i<customBlankWrapperChild.length;i++){      
       /* This condition will check each div with class name 'custom_blank' is blank or not */
       if(customBlankWrapperChild[i].className=="custom_blank" && customBlankWrapperChild[i].childElementCount<1 && customBlankWrapperChild[i].innerText==''){
          emptyBlankWrapperChildCount=emptyBlankWrapperChildCount+1;
       }       
    }
    //It will check is all 'custom_blank' div is empty or not, under the current 'custom_blank_wrapper' class.
    if(customBlankWrapperChildCount==emptyBlankWrapperChildCount){
      /* if you want to delete only 'custom_blank_wrapper' div */
        $(this).remove();
     /*if you want to delete parent of current 'custom_blank_wrapper' div */
        // $(this).parent().remove();
     /*if you want to delete parent of parent ,of  the current 'custom_blank_wrapper' div*/
         //$(this).parent().parent().remove();
    } 
 });
```

Comment: it will remove all div

Comment: Did you tried this code yet? This will only remove the div, if it’s empty.

Comment: Yeah I tried it removes all the empty div

Comment: it will remove all empty i want to remove only div which has all blank div basically first .custompsps div will be not affected another will be removed

Comment: @Sunny I'm not clear about your requirement. Please, Can you share your expected result after your main code?

Comment: i have 16 products each row consist 4 products which is div custompsps i want to remove empty tag only which row has all custom_blank div empty if it founds one filled custom_blank div then that row will be skipped

Comment: I have posted my incomplete js can you please solve it

Comment: @Sunny, Check the code now.

Comment: I have got my answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you?
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

```
span:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

If you can write code, it is better to add an additional class like `empty` and set style.

```
.empty { display: none; }
```

Comment: it will remove all empty i want to remove only div which has all blank div basically first .custompsps div will be not affected

Comment: @Sunny
:not(.custompsps):empty {}

Answer (score 0):

### Create a special selector (emptyChildren)

You can create a special selector for this:

```js
$.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {  
  emptyChildren: function (el, index, selector) {
    var childClass = selector[3];
    var element = $(el);
    var areAllChildrenEmpty = true;
    element.find(childClass).each(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(":empty")) {
            areAllChildrenEmpty = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    return areAllChildrenEmpty;
  }
});
```

### Usage

Now you can use the selector as follows:

```js
$(".custom_blank_wrapper:emptyChildren(.custom_blank)").remove();
```

### Complete example

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="custompsps">
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
            <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
            <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
                <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
                <div class="custom_blank">new</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="custompsps">
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
            <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            <div class="custom_blank"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductItem">
        <div class="ProductItem">
            <div class="custom_blank_wrapper">
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
                <div class="custom_blank"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {  
  emptyChildren: function (el, index, selector) {
    var childClass = selector[3];
    var element = $(el);
    var areAllChildrenEmpty = true;
    element.find(childClass).each(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(":empty")) {
            areAllChildrenEmpty = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    return areAllChildrenEmpty;
  }
});

$(".custom_blank_wrapper:emptyChildren(.custom_blank)").remove();
</script>
```